# Происхождение слова "рассусоливать"

Tags: этимология

"Рассусоливать" - растягивать надолго какой-то рассказ, говорить долго и невнятно, переливать из пустого в порожнее. А вот интересно было бы узнать происхождение этого слова.
Долго искал пример типичного рассусоливания и нашел Кличко и его знаменитое "...вернее смотреть могут не только лишь все, мало кто может это делать..." По-моему, очень яркий пример.)))

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово, думаю, образовалось от слова СУСЛИТЬ.

**Суслить (`Толковый словарь Ефремовой`)**
несов. перех. разг.-сниж.
1. Медленно пить или сосать, причмокивая. 2. Пачкать слюной или чем-л. жирным.

**Суслить (`Толковый словарь Ожегова`)**
-лю, -лишь; несов., что (прост.).
1. Обсасывать, мусолить. С. леденец. 2. Пачкать слюной. II сов. засуслить, -лю, -лишь; -ленный (ко 2 знач.).